# Не все ссылки отправляються в чат телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В телеграм боте не отправляеться все ссылки. Только первая https://www.lifecell.ua/uk/pro_lifecell/kariera/programa-jump/ При выборе, в других условия почему то отправляеться только эта ссылка.

Все три, работают коректно, а вот ссылки нет (выделил жирними какая ссылка работает, и курсивом какие не работают (при их вызове почему-то выводиться первая))

При том что с почтой все работает. При выборе

```
bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV hire.talents@lifecell.com.ua')
bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV telecomgo@lifecell.com.ua')
bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV reload@lifecell.com.ua')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить?

```
    import requests
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove

class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.base_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/'

    def get_updates(self, offset=None):
        method = 'getUpdates'
        params = {'offset': offset, 'timeout': 100}
        response = self._make_request(method, params)
        return response.get('result', [])

    def send_message(self, chat_id, text, reply_markup=None):
        method = 'sendMessage'
        params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': reply_markup.to_dict() if reply_markup else None}
        self._make_request(method, params)

    def send_link(self, chat_id, link):
        method = 'sendMessage'
        params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': link}
        self._make_request(method, params)

    def _make_request(self, method, params):
        url = f'{self.base_url}{method}'
        response = requests.post(url, json=params)
        return response.json()

def main():
    # Вставте сюди токен вашого бота
    bot_token = '6891551042:AAGiXQlnReKYKd-9zHhLN97-vlwCZeCPlfs'

    bot = TelegramBot(bot_token)

    print("Bot is running. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
    
    try:
        update_id = None
        while True:
            updates = bot.get_updates(offset=update_id)
            for update in updates:
                update_id = update['update_id'] + 1
                message = update.get('message')
                if message:
                    chat_id = message['chat']['id']
                    text = message.get('text', '')
                    
                    if text == '/start':
                        # Вітаємо користувача та пропонуємо вибрати опції
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['/Стажування', '/Відкриті вакансії']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Привіт! Що Вас цікавить?', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    elif text == '/Стажування':
                        # Відповідь для вибору "Стажування"
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['HIRE TALENTS, TRAIN SKILLS', 'ТЕЛЕКОМ GO', 'RELOAD', 'Назад']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Для молодих талантів у нас є декілька варіантів стажування, що було б цікаво?', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    elif text == 'HIRE TALENTS, TRAIN SKILLS':
                        # Відповідь для вибору "HIRE TALENTS, TRAIN SKILLS"
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою hire.talents@lifecell.com.ua', 'Відвідати наш сайт', 'Назад']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, '"HIRE TALENTS, TRAIN SKILLS" - це програма стажування для молодих талантів, з якими ми плануємо побудувати спільне майбутнє. Програма спрямована на опанування професії та початок розвитку кар’єри у лайфселл для студентів та випускників.', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    elif text == 'Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою hire.talents@lifecell.com.ua':
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV hire.talents@lifecell.com.ua')
                    elif text == 'Відвідати наш сайт':
                        # Відкриваємо сайт
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, **'https://www.lifecell.ua/uk/pro_lifecell/kарiera/programa-jump/')**
                    elif text == 'ТЕЛЕКОМ GO':
                        # Відповідь для вибору "ТЕЛЕКОМ GO"
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Подай заявку', 'Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою telecomgo@lifecell.com.ua', 'Відвідати наш сайт', 'Назад']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ТЕЛЕКОМ GO - це програма навчання для майбутніх telecom інженерів', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    elif text == 'Подай заявку':
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSerH2ucco9BMLHlrbfVoYHGRud67uwss2fBr0KhAiHgXiGBuQ/closedform')
                    elif text == 'Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою telecomgo@lifecell.com.ua':
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV telecomgo@lifecell.com.ua')
                    elif text == 'Відвідати наш сайт':
                        # Відкриваємо сайт
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, *'https://www.lifecell.ua/uk/pro_lifecell/kарiera/telekom-go/')*
                    elif text == 'RELOAD':
                        # Відповідь для вибору "RELOAD"
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою reload@lifecell.com.ua', 'Відвідати наш сайт', 'Назад']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Запрошуємо в програму Reload, унікальна програма де Ви зможете отримати базові знання в одному із направлень ІТ сфери', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    elif text == 'Можете відправити своє резюме за адресою reload@lifecell.com.ua':
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, 'Ось пошта за якою Ви можете відправити нам своє CV reload@lifecell.com.ua')
                    elif text == 'Відвідати наш сайт':
                        # Відкриваємо сайт
                        bot.send_link(chat_id, *'https://www.lifecell.ua/uk/pro_lifecell/kарiera/reload/')*
                    elif text == '/Відкриті вакансії':
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Ви обрали опцію "Відкриті вакансії".')
                    elif text == 'Назад':
                        # Повертаємо користувача на початковий вибір
                        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['/Стажування', '/Відкриті вакансії']], resize_keyboard=True)
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Цікавить стажування чи відкриті вакансії?', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                    else:
                        # Ваша логіка обробки інших повідомлень тут
                        response_text = f'Ви сказали: {text}'
                        bot.send_message(chat_id, response_text, reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nBot stopped.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не отправляються все ссылки, работает только первая. И](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1553735/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%98)

Comment: вместо создания дубликата лучше было внести правку в уже существующий вопрос.

Comment: сорри, я новичек, поправил, и дубликат удалил

Answer (score 0):

Подумав, решил вопрос)
Нужно было просто сделатьразный текст в при выводе каждой ссылки, а у меня был один и тот же elif text == 'Відвідати наш сайт'